# What is the verb of having a secret lover?

Tags: single-word-requests

It was just a random thought but I didn't manage to find the verb though, hope I'll explain my request clearly..

In Chinese we use the word like: *to nurture (somebody on the basis of money*), or *to raise* **(but those words are really derogatory though)** to indicate having a secret lover, like a man *nurtures* the girl even though he already has a wife; he gives the girl (younger than him usually) money and they're mainly sexually connected.
Does English have some verbs like that?

can someone help? do you understand my explanation? It's always hard for me to explain some Chinese things in English!

Answer (score 1):

Two words come to mind:

1. [philander](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/philander): His philandering became his downfall.
2. [womanize](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/womanize): He is divorced because he was a terrible womanizer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a verb for that in English.

However, a person who *is* a secret lover is called a **paramour** (rare word though). The secret meeting is often described as **clandestine meeting**.

Secret lovers often meet clandestinely in **lover's lane**.

Edit: The closest verb I could come up with is **fornicate** which means *to make love to someone you are not married to* but it doesn't connote *secretly*.

Comment: i got u, but for me fornicate is more like the act of having sexual relationships with others, not like the fact that the man/woman gives their lovers money, the Chinese word focus more on "raise," kinda like the thing a sugar daddy does. lol i know it may be weird tho, but thanks for your words

Comment: I think that the bolded words are all inappropriate: they are old-fashioned and clichéd. *Fornicate* is definitely the wrong word.